# How to control WPF window from C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am a bit confused regarding C# WPF. How can I set a WPF window's properties from C# code? For example, trying `ShowInTaskbar = false;` doesn't hide the window's taskbar button, I actually have to do it in XAML for it to work. And that wouldn't be a problem, but I wonder, how do I control the GUI from C# code when using WPF.

This may sound like a retarded question, but I am trying to transition from WinForms to WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply need the instance/reference of `Window` then you can do whatever you want with it in code.

try `windowInstance.ShowInTaskBar = false` in code it should work

Comment: That's why I am confused. The window instance doesn't have a `ShowInTaskbar` property, it has `ShowInTaskbarProperty` and it is readonly.

Comment: Ah, yeah, nevermind. Seems I'm stupid. I will accept your answer in 7 minutes, when I am allowed. Thank you.